# A question of proposition 3.1, chapter4 in hartshorne

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

[image]

As in the picture says, hartshorne says there exists a exact sequece of sheaves
$$0 \to \mathcal{L}(D-P) \to \mathcal{L}(D) \to k(p) \to 0 $$ where $\mathcal{L}(D)$ means associated invertible sheaves with the corresponding cartier divisor D. I have no idea how does this exact sequence of invertible sheaves come from. Can anyone give some hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Proposition II.6.18, you have that $\mathcal{L}(-P)$ is the ideal sheaf of the closed subscheme $\iota:\{P\}\hookrightarrow X$ (with reduced induced closed subscheme structure). Hence we have a SES
$$
0\to\mathcal{L}(-P)\to\mathcal{O}_X\to\iota_*\mathcal{O}_{\{P\}}\to 0.
$$
Now tensor with $\mathcal{L}(D)$ and use the projection formula on the last term to see that it stays the same, and convince yourself that $\iota_*\mathcal{O}_{\{P\}}=k(P)$.

Comment: Thanks very much. I still have one question. In proposition 6.18,  L(-P) is the ideal sheaf of the associated locally principal closed subscheme of effective cartier divisor P. Do you mean this locally principal closed subscheme is the same thing as when you view this cartier divisor P as a weil divisor(so it is a closed subscheme of codimension one)?I think it is right. What's the general result of this?

Comment: @Sunhf Yes, this is precisely how the correspondence between Cartier divisors and Weil divisors works on a 'nice' scheme (locally factorial etc). In Proposition II.6.11 the correspondence between Cartier divisors and Weil divisors is spelled out, and with the description above Proposition II.6.18 of the correspondence between effective Cartier divisors and locally prinicpal closed subschemes you should convince yourself that this precisely amounts to viewing the corresponding Weil divisor as a closed subscheme.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply, I previously checked it by proposition 6.11, but didn't find it on the book. Thank you!